# Ckeditor image upload - custom message when clicking ok

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ckeditor, image-upload

IE 9 does not show a progress bar when uploading an image through ckeditor.
This is very userunfriendly as users do not see any progress and wont wait up to a minute or two for large images beeing uploaded.

In the dialogbox, after sending the image to the server, one has to click the ok button.

My question: How to modify config.js or another file to show a simple message like "PLEASE WAIT, WE ARE UPLOADING YOUR IMAGE. THIS MAY NEED SOME TIME", after clicking the OK button ?

This is my first question and it is as well the first time that I couldn´t find a solution here !!!

Thank You so far !

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor/CKFinder does have a status bar:

[image: Pic of status bar]

You simply have to press "Browse Server" while in the "Image Info" tab and the above menu will appear. An easier solution would be to make people use that function instead of the "Upload" tab, which doesn't have any transfer indicators. In any case, to modify dialogs check out [this sample page](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7487/_samples/api_dialog.html) (source code has extra info), and [this API page](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html). The [Dialog Windows section](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto) of the How-To guides also explain how you can change dialogs.